# css - on large screens, two columns, on small screens one column with dynamic height

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I want data from list (on image) to be shown in 2 or more columns and container should be fixed size for large screens and to be shown in one column  in container with dynamic height. Here is image:

[image]

Tried `flexbox` with fixed height and `flex-direction:column` by default, and in media query for `width < 768`, `height: auto` and `flex-direction: row` but doesn't work. Anyone help?

Comment: add code snippet here for better understanding...

Comment: I think my question is clear enough. On left side on image is data I want to be shown in container. In the middle of image, there is container for large screens and it should be fixed height, and data should be shown in multiple columns. And on the image's right, there is container for smaller screens, one column and auto height (depending on data). That is what I want to achieve....anything unclear now?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple flexbox, just remove the fixed height on small screens

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
  height: 200px;
}

.flex div {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .flex { height: auto; }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
</div>
```